# How to insert multiple rows into multiple column of single table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i want to insert  multiple rows in multiple columns in single query using two different temp tables named `#temp1` having col QID and `#temp2` having col RID and i tried like this

```
insert into table1(ID,quetion,rating) select @ID,QID,RID from #Temp1,#temp2
```

when i am inserting the data it looking  like this

```
 ID  Quest   Rate
    2   1   5
    2   2   5
    2   3   5
    2   1   4
    2   2   4
    2   3   4
    2   1   3
    2   2   3
    2   3   3
```

but i want to insert like this

```
ID  Quest Rate
2   1   5
2   2   4
2   3   3
```

Thank in Advance:

Comment: You are currently performing a cross join. We need to know what the structure of your temp tables are and how they relate

Answer (score 1):

As table #temp1 and #temp2 don't have common columns you can use CTE and row_number() to get the required results as:

```
;WITH #temp1tbl (commonid, qid) 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    ORDER BY qid) AS CommonId, 
                qid 
         FROM   #temp1), 
     #temp2tbl (commonid, rid) 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS CommonId, 
                rid 
         FROM   #temp2) 
INSERT INTO table1 
            (id, 
             quest, 
             rating) 
SELECT @ID, 
       qid, 
       rid 
FROM   #temp1tbl 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp2tbl 
                    ON #temp1tbl.commonid = #temp2tbl.commonid
```

Comment: +1 Nice idea, but assumes increasing QIDs match increasing RIDs, which may not be the case.

Comment: Yeah..as there was no column in common i added row_numbers() to each temp table and based on sample data posted ..mapped increasing QID's with decreasing RID's.

Comment: @deepshikha: Thank u it's working but there is an issue with the Rating. Rate should insert in given order but it is inserting asc or des order.

Comment: If no ordering is required replace ORDER BY RID desc with ORDER BY (select 1) . Updated the answer. Hope this helped!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cross join` to insert NxM rows, where N is the number of rows in #Temp1 and M the number of rows in #temp2:

```
insert into table1(ID, quetion, rating) 
select @ID, t1.QID, t2.RID 
from #Temp1 t1
cross join #Temp2 t2
```

If the rows in both temporary tables are related, use a regular join:

```
insert into table1(ID, quetion, rating) 
select @ID, t1.QID, t2.RID 
from #Temp1 t1
join #Temp2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

This usually inserts less than NxM rows.

Comment: The lack of 2-part naming for columns in the Askers initial query suggests to me that `RID` and `QID` are not in both tables.

Comment: @Andomar: Thanks for response i tried even cross join which is giving the same result                                                   NOTE: both the temp tables have single column only